# Why is PCTSTR not defined but LPCTSTR defined?

Tags: visual-c++, winapi, tchar

I have been assigned to update an old code written in MSVC++ 6. I have been getting unknown definition for PCTSTR but it was not defined even if I included the tchar.h. In my previous experience I know there is an LPTSTR but no PCTSTR.

I grep the C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\Include\ folder and did not found a definition of PCTSTR. But to my surprise when I searched the Windows SDK folder [C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDK] there was no definition of PCTSTR but it was used in one of the samples. [C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDK\Samples\winui\Resource\Iconpro*]. So I am guessing that this may just be a relic from the Windows API of 16-bit windows but I cannot find any thing from google.

Does anyone know what is the PCTSTR for. I am guessing since this was from an old code that this works before. Any ideas how to make this compile? [I changed this to LPCTSTR and it compiled, I want to know if there are other ways than changing the definition name]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The LP in LPCTSTR means Long Pointer.  It is an artifact back from the Windows 3 days, a 16 bit operating system.  16-bit code had several memory models to deal with trying to address more than 65536 bytes of memory when you only have a 16-bit cpu register.  A short pointer used the default data segment register value and a 16-bit offset.  A long pointer was 32-bits, 16-bits to load a segment register and 16-bits for the offset.

The T in LPCTSTR means TCHAR, a typedef for char or wchar_t, depending on the presence of the UNICODE macro.

Which makes PCTSTR a time anachronism, humans-and-dinosaurs movie style.  There was never a 16-bit Unicode version of Windows, 32-bit versions of Windows always use 32-bit pointers.  It sounds merely like a mistake.  Enshrined though, the current version of winnt.h *does* have a typedef for it, making it the same as LPCTSTR.  And used in only *one* place, the stralign.h header with a strange function named TSTR_ALIGNED_STACK_COPY.  However only in a comment.

Mistake.  Your workaround was the right choice.

Comment: When I read your writes, sometimes, I have an illusion because you look like Raymond Chen. :)

Comment: Hehe, we're about the same age, might have something to do with it.

Comment: Wow. Raymond Chen has lived at SO, though. Did you know that? http://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen

Answer (score 0):

In Windows SDK v7.0a I have on my machine, `WinNT.h` contains two different typedefs for PCTSTR, depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined. In both cases, `LPCTSTR` is defined the same way - so these two are equivalent nowadays.