# Upload file using HTTP. getting error :- HttpSendReuest 12005

Tags: php, c++, file, http, upload

I want to upload "D:\er.txt" to webserver using HTTP, when I am running program, i got HttpSendRequest 12005 as an error.  i used a PHP script on my webserver that will accept the file and stores it in a pre-made directory named as "upload".. here is my tiny program

```
int main()
{
    static TCHAR frmdata[] = "-----------------------------7d82751e2bc0858\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"D:\\er.txt\"\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\nfile contents  here\r\n-----------------------------7d82751e2bc0858--\r\n";
    static TCHAR hdrs[] = "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7d82751e2bc0858";

    HINTERNET hSession = InternetOpen("MyAgent",INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
    if(!hSession)
    {
        cout<<"Error: InternetOpen";
    }


    HINTERNET hConnect = InternetConnect(hSession, _T("http://jobnews.netii.net/upload.php"),INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
    if(!hConnect)
    {
        cout<<"Error: InternetConnect";
    }

    HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, (const char*)"POST",_T("upload.php"), NULL, NULL, (const char**)"*/*\0", 0, 1);
    if(hRequest==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"Error: HttpOpenRequest";
    }

    BOOL sent= HttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdrs, strlen(hdrs), frmdata, strlen(frmdata));
    if(!sent)
    {
        cout<<"Error: HttpSendRequest "<<GetLastError();
    }


    //close any valid internet-handles
    InternetCloseHandle(hSession);
    InternetCloseHandle(hConnect);
    InternetCloseHandle(hRequest);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

and my PHP script is

```
<?php
$uploaddir = 'upload/'; // Relative Upload Location of data file

if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'])) {
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
echo "File ". $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'] ." uploaded successfully. ";
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
echo "File is valid, and was successfully moved. ";
}

else
print_r($_FILES);
}

else {
echo "Upload Failed!!!";
print_r($_FILES);
}
?>
```

Comment: is this some sort of assignment? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985345/dev-c-wininet-upload-file-using-http

Comment: no no.. not at all.  i am a beginner in development field, and i am try to understand the concepts by going through some working examples. this is just for study purpose only

Comment: The error message you quote is saying "invalid URL".  If what other people are saying about mis-use of string references is correct, that would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs for [HttpOpenRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384233%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the `lplpszAcceptTypes` argument should change from

```
(const char**)"*/*\0"
```

to

```
{_T("*/*"), NULL}
```

You can also remove the `\0` from the end of the string.  You don't need to manually insert a nul terminator to a string literal.

In other words, you need to change

```
HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, (const char*)"POST",
                                     _T("upload.php"), NULL, NULL,
                                     (const char**)"*/*\0", 0, 1);
```

to

```
LPCTSTR rgpszAcceptTypes[] = {_T("*/*"), NULL};
HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, (const char*)"POST",
                                     _T("upload.php"), NULL, NULL,
                                     rgpszAcceptTypes, 0, 1);
```

Comment: @user2682006 He's saying pass a `LPCTSTR*` like the documentation he linked indicates is required. Your cast is not only incorrect, it is invalid. `LPCTSTR arAccentTypes[] = {_T("*/*"), NULL};`. Pass *that* (by-value, no indirection, casts, etc. required).

Comment: @user2682006 I've updated my answer to be more explicit about the problem.

Comment: sir i am using DEV C++ and after putting your lines in it, it's showing `PCTSTR' undeclared (first use this function) error

Comment: I might have copied from msdn too liberally, try using `LPCTSTR` instead.  And see [this previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9063401/311966) for some details on the two types.

Comment: after replacing some lines suggested by you, my program compiles successfully but on debugging it still showing the same error "HttpSendRequest 12005" as an error :(